# Is it possible to let VBA change cell interior color after sheet has been locked using UserInterfaceOnly?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on an extensive fillable workbook for some time now. I've now arrived at the end and I want to protect the workbook. I read on stackoverflow that, when using macro's, the best way to lock a worksheet is using UserInterfaceOnly. So, I added the following code:

```
Private Sub Lock_cells()
Worksheet("3. Keuze").Range("C3:C5,C7,C9,C13").Locked = False
Worksheet("3. Keuze").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

The cells C3:C5, C7, C9 and C13 must remain open to fill in. When the cell is cleared by the user, the cell interior color should change to yellow. When the cell is filled with a value, the interior color should change to green. To make that happen I created the following code:

```
If Target.Address = "C3" Then
Call Fill_in_color1
End If

Sub Fill_in_color1
If IsEmpty(Cells(7,3).Value) = False Then
Cells(7,3).InteriorColor = RGB(112,173,71) 'GREEN
Cells(7,3).FontColor = vbWhite
Else
Cells(7,3).InteriorColor = RGB(255,255,231) 'YELLOW
Cells(7,3).Font.Color = vbBlack
End If
End Sub
```

When locking the worksheet, the correct cells are locked and I am able to edit the proper cells. However, when I clear cell C3 for instance, VBA gives me an error message:
*Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error*
It seems that the locked worksheet is blocking VBA from changing the interior color.

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` gets lost on every closing of the workbook. So make sure you protect your workbook in the `Worksheet_Open()` event using `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` so it gets applied to the workbook on every re-opening.

Comment: In which line of the code do you get the error?

Comment: Why use VBA to change the cell color based on its value? That sounds like a job for conditional formatting.

Comment: @JoshEller That's what I thought at first but it might interfere with *"When the cell is cleared by the user, the cell interior color should change to yellow."* If the initial (empty) state was not yellow. But if that is not an issue, and epmty means always yellow then conditional formatting will be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the following in the following order in your sub:

1. Un-protect the worksheet
2. Update the locked/un-locked properties of your cells
3. change the values or colors of the cells
4. re-lock cells *(if necessary)*
5. re-protect the worksheet